# How to implement a custom rotate container/widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I would like to implement this effect but idk where to start.
https://uimovement.com/ui/7370/explore-recipes/

I've tried using AnimatedContainers but maybe it's a the wrong widget.

I need advice or an example where to start or research.

This is my dummy code:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      color: Colors.white,
      child: new AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: animationController,
        child: new Container(
          height: 300.0,
          width: 300.0,
          child: new Image.asset('images/food.png'),
        ),
        builder: (BuildContext context, Widget _widget) {
          return new Transform.rotate(
            angle: animationController.value * 6.3,
            child: _widget,
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Hi. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Post your code, please.

Comment: @RubensMelo maybe I should use Gestures?

Comment: Yep. You have to start animation after `pressed` or`tap` event.